# Can I prevent mysql from join on partial match for varchar field?

Tags: mysql

I have two records with an item number field start with '01088', but one record has a 'Y' at the end of the item number.

When I try to join another table on that field, it joins on both records even though there's only a matching record for '01088'

I've tried explicitly casting the field to `CHAR(20)`, but it doesn't make a difference.

Why is the join matching together '01088' and '01088Y'?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82ffa/19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the left join, make it an INNER JOIN, otherwise you return All from the left table and null where there is no match in the right.

Sara